# Discord Python Bot play Music - url is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm currently onto coding a discord bot using python and ran into a problem. I try to let my bot play music using a "play" command.

> My Code:

```
@bot.command(name='play')
async def play(self, ctx, url : str):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'> Du musst in einem Voice Channel sein, um diesen Befehl zu verwenden.', description='Diese Nachricht wird nach 15 Sekunden automatisch gelöscht.', color=embed_color, timestamp=datetime.now().astimezone(tz=de))
        embed.add_field(name='⠀', value='⠀')
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Angefordert von {ctx.author.name} • {ctx.author.id}', icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        bot_msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(15)
        await bot_msg.delete()
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.moce_to(voice_channel)
            
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client
        
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)
```

But when running the command I get following error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: url is a required
> argument that is missing.

Why is that?

PS: What I type in the discord channel: ".play [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0woPCb5xk8"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0woPCb5xk8%22)
So I'm obviously giving it a url to work with... :c

Comment: Is your `play()` function within a class? If not, remove the `self` parameter.

Comment: Working just fine now... Thanks! :D
PS: I first used it inside a class but then moved it...

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :)